# Show JavaScript on click

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code

```
<div class="AW-Form-2026756516"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "http://forms.aweber.com/form/16/2026756516.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, "script", "aweber-wjs-ielieh3he"));
</script>
```

It shows a lightbox subscription form.

But I would like this to be displayed once a user has clicked on a Button and not automatically.

```
<div id="subscribe"><a href="">Subscribe</a></div>
```

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: You need to use onclick event!

Comment: jquery can also be a replacement for this. Js answers have been posted. Lemme know if you need jquery solution also..

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener

Answer (score 1):

```
Use onclick event

<div class="AW-Form-2026756516">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowSubscribe(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "http://forms.aweber.com/form/16/2026756516.js';
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }
</script>
<div id="subscribe">
    <a href="#" onclick="ShowSubscribe(document, 'script', 'aweber-wjs-ielieh3he');">Subscribe</a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using button to trigger event. Try this.

```
<div class="AW-Form-2026756516"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function ShowSubscribe()
{
    (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "http://forms.aweber.com/form/16/2026756516.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, "script", "aweber-wjs-ielieh3he"));
}
</script>

<div id="subscribe">
<button onclick="ShowSubscribe()">Click me</button> 
</div>
```

Comment: Why the `javascript:` [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label)? And onclick attributes this century?

Comment: Thanks, it opens in a separate pop-up window. Anyway to open it within the same window with a lightbox effect.

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="AW-Form-2026756516"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowSubscribe()
    {
        (function(d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "http://forms.aweber.com/form/16/2026756516.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, "script", "aweber-wjs-ielieh3he"));
    }
</script>


<div id="subscribe">
    <a href="javascript:ShowSubscribe()">Subscribe</a>
</div>
```